# Read in loop, the content of HTML pages with Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to create Google Chrome Extension that does the following things :

Read an array of urls (it is possible to have 2000 urls)
For each url :
1) I display the page in a tab
2) I extract some html content in the new loaded page
3) I built a new url with the extracted content for send information to my own local service, it saves the information (I suppose, I just need to update the tab with this new url)

After that, it's ok, I just do again the same tasks with the next url.

To begin to do this job, I have created this 3 following files.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test to read pages",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "test page reader",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**
This file loads directly the popup.js

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: 15px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
urls = ["http://localhost/page1.php",
        "http://localhost/page2.php",
        "http://localhost/page3.php"
];

for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 
    myUrl = urls[i]+"&current="+i; // add "current" parameter to know where I am

    // callback function
    callbackFct = function() {
        // affecte le style de la div
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };

    // update tab and execute callbackFct
    chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:myUrl}, callbackFct);

}
```

**I have a problem with my code :**

> The callback function modify the background color of the popup.html and not the background of the page. 
>   How shall I do for modify the content of the tab and not the content of the popup.html ? When this operation will be ok, I could replace by the data extraction (step 2).
>   Is it the write way to use a callback function after I have updated the tab ? 
>   The goal is to wait until the DOM page is fully loaded.
>   (Step 3) Where is the best place to call my service in order to save the data ? Is-it in the callback function with an update of the current tab ?

Thanks a lot by advance for your help and advices.